# How to batch compress folders?

Tags: compression, batch, 7zip

I want to batch compress folders, I want the format to be 7zip and of course I want to preserve the name and get the `.7z` extension at the end.

Comment: Have you considered writing a script? Bash isn't too hard to learn and you can test it until you get it right....

Comment: well if it works I have no problem with that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as Elder Geek suggested I used a bash script

This is the script I used

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in */
do
  7z a -mx7 -mmt "${folder%/}.7z" "$folder"
done
```

You can **personalize** this part to your preferences, [more information on this](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm)

```
7z a -mx7 -mmt
```

If you do not want to read that article, this is what information will be very useful: you see **-mx7** in above line, if yes you can set the last number from 0 to 9. That will tell 7 zip what compression mode to use 0 means store and 9 is ultra mode so if you write -mx0 it will compress very fast but the file size will be big. if you write -mx9 then compression will take more time but the file size will be small.

So what do you do with above text. You create a text document you paste the above text into it and save it. you can name it what ever you want, for example (**test**)

then open **terminal** and **cd** into the directory where your folders are that you want to compress.

type in the terminal: **bash** then space and drag and drop your created text file into terminal and press enter. 
 you terminal commend might look like something like this

```
bash '/home/uname/Desktop/test'
```

it will start compressing and after it is finished you will have your compressed files.

Comment: Nicely done. Is the `-mmt` working to multithread or do we need `-mmt=on`?

Comment: I believe it is enabled with -mmt but you can specify it if you want

Comment: `top` will tell the tale. System monitor will also show usage of multiple cores (without the detail)

Comment: Likewise this could work for other compression methods such as `tar` too. For example:  `for folder in */; do tar -zcvf "${folder%/}.tar.gz" "$folder"; done`  .

Comment: Nice this helped to compress in batch.